# Disconnected hose on a 2018 Ram Promaster 1500?

Tags: air-intake, ram

So I was helping my friend change his oil on his 2018 Ram Promaster 1500. I noticed a hose which was just sticking straight up within the engine bay on the driver's side. I have absolutely no idea what it's for. Considering it's been driving for potentially thousands of miles with it disconnected, I'm assuming it's some kind of air intake. It's not super clear from the photo, but the other end of the tube is more rectangular. Since I'm assuming it's not supposed to be dangling like that, I'd love to know where it got disconnected from.

[image]